# Adding a custom template file to be shown on a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

So I created a custom `Location` post type and a custom `Location Page Template` but I am not able to assign the `Location Page Template` to the `Location` posts.

The top of my `Location Page Template` looks like this:

`/*
Template Name: Location
Template Post Type: Location
*
*/`

I required the template in my `functions.php` file like this:

`require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/locations.php';`

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Location Page Template` I referred to the WordPress template hierarchy and used the `single-[posttype].php` so in my case `single-locations.php`. The diagram linked below was a helpful reference. [http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)